# Netlogo and GIS extension unsupported projection file

Tags: gis, netlogo, arcgis, agent-based-modeling

I am trying to import my ARCGIS Pro project to Netlogo and I am getting this error.

Extension exception: unsupported projection 'Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere'
error while observer running GIS:LOAD-DATASET
  called by procedure SETUP-MAP
  called by Button 'setup-map'

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, go to the NetLogo User Manual section on the GIS extension. In the documentation for the primitive gis:load-coordinate-system, you will find a list of the projections that the extension can use. You will see that it can use several Mercator projections but not yours. So ideally you can fix this by going back to the GIS and saving your shapefile in one of the projections that NetLogo uses.

(I know almost nothing about GIS but: the GIS technician I work with often saves shapefiles for me in the Lambert_Conformal_Conic projection, while the GIS extension accepts only the Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP projection. We have learned to trick NetLogo by editing the shapefile’s .prj file to change the text "Lambert_Conformal_Conic" to "Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP". That makes the GIS extension think that we're using one of its projections, and it works. You could try this trick to tell NetLogo you're using one of the Mercator projections.)